# View a contact photo in a 3-layer architecture in a picturebox C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to write a phonebook in C # with a three-layer architecture, but I do not have enough of this architecture.
We have a datagridview that displays the image of each person in the picturebox when we click on each of the rows.
But it does not work. I do not know where the problem is. Please guide me. I recently got acquainted with this architecture.

DAL code:

```
 public void GetBinaryImage(int Id)
    {

        context.People.Select(a => new { a.Id, a.PersonImage }).Where(a => a.Id == Id) ;

    }
```

BLL code

```
 public void GrtBinaryImage(int person_Id)
    {

        Myperson.GetBinaryImage(person_Id);

    }
```

PL code

```
 private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Id"].Value);
            showpictureBox.Image = bytearytoimage(person.GrtBinaryImage(Id));


        }
    }

    private Image bytearytoimage(object v)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(v);
        return Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
```

I get the error:

> "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to object".

I know I wrote a mistake, please guide me.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: I get the error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to object".

Comment: your GrtBinaryImage method from BLL is not returning any values i guess it should return an object which is required in bytearytoimage
please update your BLL method

Comment: What do you think of the object should be returned to this BLL method?

Comment: i guess it should return byteArray as your bytearytoimage method expects

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You seem to a have a lack of understanding with returning values from functions.

First of all your DLL function doesn't return anything, I can only assume you are trying to return `PersonImage` which is hopefully a `byte[]`. In addition, you need to change the code to select only the value you want to return:

**DLL**

```
public byte[] GetBinaryImage(int Id)
{
    byte[] result = context.People.Where(a => a.Id == Id).Select(a => a.PersonImage).SingleOrDefault();
    return result;
}
```

Next up, you have the same problem with return values in your BLL:

**BLL**

```
public byte[] GrtBinaryImage(int person_Id)
{
    return Myperson.GetBinaryImage(person_Id);
}
```

That should be enough to get what you want, although I would also recommend changing the parameter type in your `bytearytoimage` function specifically to `byte[]`:

**PL**

```
private Image bytearytoimage(byte[] v)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(v);
    return Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Note that this all hinges on the fact that `PersonImage` is a `byte[]`. If it isn't then you should update your question to be more specific about what data you have to work with.